# Positivity of eigenvalues of tridiagonal, almost-Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

> How can one show that the following tridiagonal matrix
>
> $$M_n= \begin{pmatrix}
> -1&3&0&\dots&\dots&\dots&0\\
> 3&2&-1&0&&&\vdots\\
> 0&-1&2&-1&\ddots&&\vdots\\
> \vdots&0&-1&2&\ddots&0&\vdots\\
> \vdots&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&-1&0\\
> \vdots&&&0&-1&2&-1\\
> 0&\dots&\dots&\dots&0&-1&2
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> has exactly one negative eigenvalue?

The initial problem was showing it has at least some number of real positive eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct) for sufficiently large $n$, which can be solved by using [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem):

Which implies $-4\le \lambda\le6$ if I'm not mistaken, since $M_n$ has real eigenvalues (it's hermitian),

Then since the trace $\operatorname{Tr}M_n =2n-3$ of a matrix is also the sum of its eigenvalues, we must have at least $\frac{2n-3}{6}$ real positive eigenvalues, otherwise $\operatorname{Tr}M_n < 2n-3$ would be a contradiction.

But I noticed $M_n$ seems to have exactly one negative real eigenvalue, and the rest positive real eigenvalues, for every $n$.

How can we prove this strict bound?

Comment: seems a pretty good, provable, pattern in solving $P^T MP = D$ becoming diagonal, with $\det P = 1.$ By Sylvester's Law of Inertia, there is one negative eigenvalue, else positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THREE:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 3 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

===========================================

FOUR:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 21 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 3 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 21 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 21 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 21 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

====================================

FIVE:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 21 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 3 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 31 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 21 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 31 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 31 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 21 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 41 }{ 31 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 21 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 41 }{ 31 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=================================

SIX:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 21 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 41 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 41 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 41 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 41 }  &  \frac{ 31 }{ 41 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 3 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 41 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 21 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 41 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 41 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 41 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 41 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 21 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 41 }{ 31 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 51 }{ 41 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 31 }{ 41 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 11 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 21 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 41 }{ 31 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 51 }{ 41 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 11 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 21 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 21 }{ 31 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 31 }{ 41 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=============================

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let us drop the subscript in $M_n$. The trailing principal $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix $P$ of $M$ is a symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix whose diagonal entries are $a=2$ and whose subdiagonal entries are $b=-1$. The eigenvalues of $P$ are therefore
$$
\lambda_k(P)=a+2b\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=2\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right)
$$
for $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$. Hence $\lambda_k(P)>0$ for every $k$ and $P$ is positive definite. However, by Cauchy's interlacing inequality for bordered matrix,
$$
\lambda_1(M)\le\lambda_1(P)\le\lambda_2(M)\le\lambda_2(P)\le
\cdots\le\lambda_{n-1}(M)\le\lambda_{n-1}(P)\le\lambda_n(M).
$$
Thus $M_n$ has at most one non-positive eigenvalue. This eigenvalue must be negative, otherwise $M$ would be positive semidefinite, which is a contradiction to the fact that the first entry of $M$ is negative.